# Implementing card flipping animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

[This is the container flipping from top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iMzE.jpg)
I am trying a card flip animation and it's not flipping from the center. It's flipping from the top portion of the container.
I am trying a card flip animation and it's not flipping from the center. It's flipping from the top portion of the container.

```
class _Container1State extends State<Container1>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation animation;
  AnimationController animationController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.linear, parent: animationController),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    animationController.forward();
    return Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animationController,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          animationController.repeat();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          transform: Matrix4.identity()
                            ..rotateX(2 * 3.14 * animation.value),
                          height: 150,
                          width: 150,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          child: Center(child: Text('Text 1')),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
[image]
Here is my simple [FlipViewWidget](https://dartpad.dev/1908f087952174904e3d2ef7d6947dce)

```
class FlipView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget front, back;

  FlipView({Key key, @required this.front, @required this.back}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FlipViewState createState() => _FlipViewState();
}

class _FlipViewState extends State<FlipView> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), vsync: this);
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        bool isFront = _controller.value < .5;
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (_animation.isDismissed) {
              _controller.forward();
            } else if (_animation.isCompleted) {
              _controller.reverse();
            }
          },
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
              ..rotateX(pi * _animation.value + (isFront ? 0 : pi)),
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: isFront ? widget.front : widget.back,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Usage

```
class FlipViewTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
          child: FlipView(
            front: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('Front', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            back: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('Back', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**OLD**

set the container inside transform widget. and than you can change alignment easily.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    animationController.forward();
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Center(
            child: Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                ..rotateX(2 * 3.14 * animation.value),
              alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  animationController.repeat();
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Text 1')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: The code heIps me in a right way but i only need a single flip to change the container to another. I don't want **double flipping** and **text invertion**.Also i have three containers inside a ternary operator(another practicing app).

Comment: you didn't mention these in your question

Comment: Sorry i am trying this the first time. I don't know how it works. How to avoid the **text inversion** over there? and **single flip** to change? Also i don't want the app to start the animation on first. I just want to animate my container when is trigger my onTap: function.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply use [flip_card](https://pub.dev/packages/flip_card)

```
FlipCard(
  direction: FlipDirection.VERTICAL,
  front: Container(
        child: Text('Front'),
    ),
    back: Container(
        child: Text('Back'),
    ),
);
```

Comment: How to implement this in a ternary operator, i am using a ternary operator with three containers.

Comment: one is front, one is back, whats the third one for? pls elaborate more